# Finding $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2(\cosh(x)-1)^{1/x^2}}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

This problem was asked in applications of L'Hospital's rule:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2(\cosh(x)-1)^{1/x^2}}{x^2}$$

I tried expansion of $\cosh(x)$ and also assuming that the limit is y and trying to find $\ln(y)$. But not working, please solve

Comment: This is indeed an application of L'hopitals rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the numerator is
$$
2\left(\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{24}+\dots\right)^{1/x^2}
=2\cdot 2^{-1/x^2}\cdot x^{2/x^2}\cdot\underbrace{\left(1+\frac{x^2}{12}+\dots\right)^{1/x^2}}_{\to e^{1/12}}
$$
so
$$
\frac{2(\cosh(x)-1)^{1/x^2}}{x^2}\sim 4e^{1/12}\underbrace{(2x^2)^{1/x^2-1}}_{\to 0}.
$$